# How do you set the encoding for parameters in Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Data REST in my project. I declared a repository with a `findByName(String name)` method. Now I try to call

```
http://my-service/my-api/search/findByName?name=test%C3%BC
```

since I want to search für `name = testü`. The API doesn't find the entity though. If I encode the `ü` using `%FC` Spring Data REST works as expected.

How can I change the encoding of my url parameters so that I can use utf-8 encoded strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8`

## Character encoding to use to decode the URI.`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html